# How to pass the -D System properties while testing on Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am developing on Eclipse on Windows and Code gets deployed on Unix. I am fetching the system property values using System.getProperty("key") ... How do I pass this in Eclipse so that I do not have to modify the code and it works on Eclipse for debugging?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Run -> Run configurations, select project, second tab: “Arguments”. Top box is for your program, bottom box is for VM arguments, e.g. `-Dkey=value`.

Comment: where is this if you are trying to run an android application?

Comment: why do I have to use 'D' as prefix?

Comment: If you're as thick as me -- *-D arguments go in the **bottom** box for VM arguments*, **not** in the top box for your program's args. /sigh

Comment: The top box is for the `String[] args` passed to the `main` method.

Comment: Is there any way to set this to happen by default, so you don't have to manually enter this repeatedly for many tests?

Comment: value is something in quotes?

Answer (score 53):

You can use java `System.properties`, for using them from eclipse you could:

1. Add `-Dlabel="label_value"` in the VM arguments of the test `Run Configuration` like this:

[image: eclipse_vm_config]

2. Then run the test:

   ```
   import org.junit.Test;
   import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

   public class Main {
       @Test
       public void test(){
           System.out.println(System.getProperty("label"));
           assertEquals("label_value", System.getProperty("label"));
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally it should pass the test and output this in the console:

   ```
   label_value
   ```

Answer (score 13):

You can add command line arguments to your run configuration. Just edit the run configuration and add -Dmyprop=value (or whatever) to the VM Arguments Box.

Comment: If you meant "Program Arguments box" when you said "command-line args box" under Arguments tab - Does not Work!
Has to be entered in "VM Arguments Box" as mentioned by Bombe above.

Answer (score 4):

This will work for junit. for TestNG use following command

```
-ea -Dmykey="value" -Dmykey2="value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the way:

Right click on your program, select run -> run configuration
then on vm argument

```
-Denv=EnvironmentName -Dcucumber.options="--tags @ifThereisAnyTag"
```

Then you can apply and close.