# Tess4j unsatisfied link error on mac OS X

Tags: java, tesseract

Hey i am trying to use tess4j for tesseract and having this issue for eclipse on mac osx .

My tesseract is working fine from terminal but trying to run tess4j through tesseract throws me an error .

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract': Native library (darwin/libtesseract.dylib)

i do have tessetact dylib and its named libtesseract.dylib in my opt/local/lib which i installed using macport .

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 18):

I know it's an old post. I had this problem too recently when I tried to use `Tess4J`. However, I managed to find a way around it. I've written a post about it http://www.microshell.com/programming/java/performing-optical-character-recognition-in-java/

In short, the problem is because `tess4j-2.0.0.jar` doesn't include MacOS library. So I just modified the maven cached jar on mine by doing these steps:

1. `cd /Users/user/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/2.0.0` (adjust the directory where your tess4j JAR file resides)
2. `mkdir darwin`
3. `jar uf tess4j-2.0.0.jar darwin`
4. `cp /opt/local/lib/libtesseract.3.dylib darwin/libtesseract.dylib`
5. `jar uf tess4j-2.0.0.jar darwin/libtesseract.dylib`
6. `jar tf tess4j-2.0.0.jar` (to verify that the file is included)

I was then able to run my Java program after I modify the `tess4j-2.0.0.jar` file. Below is my MacOS version.

```
user@laptop:~$ uname -a
Darwin Maresas-MacBook-Pro.local 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! For those that installed it with `brew install tesseract`, the 4th step should be similar to `cp /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/lib/libtesseract.4.dylib darwin/libtesseract.dylib` :)

Comment: This was an EXCELLENT addition to this post, Thank you! You saved me potentially hours of work to figure this out.

Comment: @maresa I wrote a library based on this answer to make it easy for people to patch their jar file: https://github.com/EasyG0ing1/FixTess4j4Mac

Answer (score 8):

@maresa after a few years your comment helped me, thanks a lot :) A bit different paths, maybe it'll help someone:

1. cd /Users/username/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/tess4j/tess4j/4.5.4/
2. mkdir darwin
3. jar uf tess4j-4.5.4.jar darwin/
4. brew info tesseract (here you can find path to libtesseract.4.dylib)
5. cp /usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/lib/libtesseract.4.dylib darwin/libtesseract.dylib
6. jar uf tess4j-4.5.4.jar darwin/libtesseract.dylib
7. jar tf tess4j-4.5.4.jar

MacOS Catalina - 10.15.3

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar issue with Ghost4j, i.e.

```
InvocationTargetException: Unable to load library 'gs': Native library (darwin/libgs.dylib) not found in resource path
```

Instead of modifying jar files, point jna to the appropriate lib path by setting `jna.library.path`. In Eclipse, you need to set the system property in run configurations - SO answer for this here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/862405/2163229

If you're using Maven exec:

```
mvn -Djna.library.path=/opt/local/lib/ exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="foo.bar.NativeThingy"
```

or

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djna.library.path=/opt/local/lib/" && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="foo.bar.NativeThingy"
```

Obviously, set the path to wherever your libs are installed. In my case, I ran `$ locate libgs.dylib` and found the above path.

**References:**
https://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html

Answer (score 5):

You need install the tesseract lib on your Mac.

`brew install tesseract --with-all-languages`

Comment: With this command. Error: invalid option: --with-all-languages

Comment: (If you installed tesseract with brew, please read my comment under @maresa 's answer ;-))

Answer (score 1):

After many year, this is still a big issues to many people who want to use Tess4j in MacOs. The issue is on Tess4j, not Tessaract. Tess4j is the java wrapper for Tessaract. Apparently the Tess4j jar file is missing a c++ library (`libtesseract.dylib`) necessary for its operation in macos.
I'll explain the steps I took to solve this for Mac users.

Tools: Gradle 8.5, JDK 21, Tessarract 5.3.4 ([from sourceforge](https://tess4j.sourceforge.net/)), Tess4j 5.10.0, Intellij, Mac Os - Sonoma 14.2.1, Kotlin 1.9.22, Spring Boot 3.2.2

1. Install Tessaract using brew `brew install tessaract`. You can use `brew list tessaract` to check where brew installed tessract. For me, brew installed it at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.4`
2. I used both the jar file and graddle dependency from [this maven repo.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j). Here is my my setup (parts of my directory and graddle.build.kts dependencies).
   [image: directory structure for tessj4 setup in graddle]

[image: graddle dependency]

The `libs` directory and everything inside it are created by me. The `libtesseract.dylib` is a renamed version of `libtesseract.5.dylib` from brew's tessaract installation. In my case, it's located at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.4/lib/libtesseract.5.dylib`. The `5` in `libtesseract.5.dylib` seems to be the tessaract version, yours might be different depending on the time you'll be reading this.

Side Note: The reason I used both the maven repo in the graddle build file as well as a jar file is that Tess4j has other dependences which the graddle dependency brings in, such as [Lept4J](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.lept4j/lept4j), which is a Java JNA wrapper for image processing. Also I didn't want to patch the `tess4j-5.10.0.jar` file built by graddle because it's stored inside a hashed folder which could change when rebuilt or version updated.

3. The last thing is to patch the jar file with the c++ library we copied.
   Open a terminal at the `libs` folder shown in the above image and run the following commands.
   i) `jar uf tess4j-5.10.0.jar darwin` - This will update the jar archive file with the `darwin` directory which you created.

ii) `jar uf tess4j-5.10.0.jar darwin/libtesseract.dylib` this will update the jar file with the library you copied.

iii) `jar tf tess4j-5.10.0.jar` (Optional) - verify the patching was successful.

At this point, you should be ready to go.

Bonus:

```kotlin
    fun getImageText(): String {
       val image = ImageIO.read(File("src/main/resources/url.png"))
        val tesseract = Tesseract()
        tesseract.setDatapath("/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.4/share/tessdata")
        tesseract.setLanguage("eng")
       // tesseract.setLanguage("jpn_vert") // japanese
        tesseract.setPageSegMode(1)
        tesseract.setOcrEngineMode(1)
       // tesseract.setVariable("tessedit_create_hocr", "1") // html output

        try {
            return tesseract.doOCR(image)
        } catch (e: TesseractException) {
            // handle error
        }
    }
```

NOTE: In case you are working with images with languages other than English, there's a way to brew more language into tessaract installation but I didn't care to search. What I did was to download the traineddata file for the language I wanted from [tessaract repo on github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) and paste it into the brew's tessaract installation.

For my case, I wanted Japanese, so I downloaded  the `jpy_vert.traineddata` and pasted the downloaded file into tessdata folder inside tessaract brew's installation, which, in my case, is `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/tesseract/5.3.4/share/tessdata/jpn_vert.traineddata`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use `libtesseract.dylib` of Tesseract 3.02 version. Check out [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/y8m_IIk767s) on Tesseract Forum.

Comment: I am using version 3.02.02, and i checked that post out before but it does not work. And i also added the java -Djava.library.path as vm argument . Can 64  bit jvm throw this error

Comment: Very possible. Tesseract and Leptonica are 32-bit libraries. Could take quite a bit of work to compile them to 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was after today, so thanks for the Q&A above. As one additional step beyond what maresa mentioned, I ran into this error after fixing the one you asked about:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/var/folders/sq/rh89_ntd7jqdlv9__25zj9dr0000gp/T/jna--913086793/jna8800789057827590119.tmp, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/liblept.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

So to fix this I needed to set up a symlink for libjpeg.8.dylib:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
```

Not sure if there is a way to do this without the symlink (i.e. package it in the jar), but I hope this helps anyone else who is looking at this post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on maresa's answer above, which works perfectly, I wrote a library that will make it easy to patch the tess4j.jar file with the appropriate C library from tesseract. [You can get it here](https://github.com/EasyG0ing1/FixTess4j4Mac).

Answer (score 0):

You should to specify the path to .dylib via `Djna.library.path` vm option.

In my case: `-Djna.library.path=/usr/local/lib`

Also this topic may be useful for you, because in my case it is need to install tesseract for x86_64 architecture:

- [How do you install the x86_64 version of a brew package on a M1 Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72970363/how-do-you-install-the-x86-64-version-of-a-brew-package-on-a-m1-mac)