# UnsatisfiedLinkError with TessAPI1 while using tess4j

Tags: java, tesseract, tess4j

I'm working on Mac OS, using tesseract to do the OCR.

I installed tesseract with homebrew.

The tesseract works well with command line, and the java program works well with the basic example of Tesseract.getInstance().

But since I want to get the confidence value of each character, I switch to use the TessAPI1 and had the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'TessResultRendererAddError': dlsym(0x7f9df9c38c20, TessResultRendererAddError): symbol not found
at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:208)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:536)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:513)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:499)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1509)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1396)
at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1156)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI1.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at TesseractWrapper.doOCR(TesseractWrapper.java:71)
at OCR.main(OCR.java:6)
```

The error occurred at

```
handle = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPICreate();
```

The code looks like below:

```
            TessAPI1.TessBaseAPI handle;

            handle = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPICreate();
            new File(this.path);
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(

            new FileInputStream(tiff)); // require jai-imageio lib to read TIFF
            ByteBuffer buf = ImageIOHelper.convertImageData(image);

            int bpp = image.getColorModel().getPixelSize();
            int bytespp = bpp / 8;
            int bytespl = (int) Math.ceil(image.getWidth() * bpp / 8.0);
            TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIInit3(handle,

            "tessdata", lang);
            TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetPageSegMode(handle, TessAPI1.TessPageSegMode.

            PSM_AUTO);
            TessAPI1.TessBaseAPISetImage(handle, buf, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), bytespp, bytespl);

            TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIRecognize(handle,

            null);
            TessAPI1.TessResultIterator ri = TessAPI1.TessBaseAPIGetIterator(handle);

            TessAPI1.TessPageIterator pi = TessAPI1.TessResultIteratorGetPageIterator(ri);

            TessAPI1.TessPageIteratorBegin(pi);
```

I found this code from some other question and I guess what I need is to get and 'iterator' and then I could get the character with its confidence value one by one.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394537/tess4j-unsatisfied-link-error-on-mac-os-x

Comment: What version of Tesseract and Tess4J are you using? Make sure they are compatible.