# How do I install tess4j in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, jar, tess4j

I have been struggling for hours now trying to install Tess4J. I tried it via maven and manually and I always get the same result.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'tesseract':
dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
dlopen(/Users/lorenz/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/lorenz/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
Native library (darwin-x86-64/libtesseract.dylib) not found in resource path (/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/target/classes:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/15.0.1/javafx-controls-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/15.0.1/javafx-controls-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/15.0.1/javafx-graphics-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/15.0.1/javafx-graphics-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/15.0.1/javafx-base-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/15.0.1/javafx-base-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/15.0.1/javafx-fxml-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/15.0.1/javafx-fxml-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jna-5.11.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/tess4j-5.2.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/lept4j-1.16.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/fontbox-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/commons-io-2.11.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jbig2-imageio-3.0.4.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-tools-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jboss-vfs-3.2.16.Final.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-debugger-2.0.26.jar)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:301)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:461)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:192)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:622)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.load(Native.java:596)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:83)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:441)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:237)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:209)
    at com.sudoku_solver.ImageProcessor.ImageReader.readImage(ImageReader.java:13)
    at com.sudoku_solver.ImageProcessor.ImageReader.main(ImageReader.java:21)
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:191)
        ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(libtesseract.dylib, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), 'libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtesseract.dylib' (no such file)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:204)
        ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Users/lorenz/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/Users/lorenz/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:248)
        ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file), '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:248)
        ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen(/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract, 0x0009): tried: '/System/Library/Frameworks/tesseract.framework/tesseract' (no such file)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:248)
        ... 11 more
    Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Native library (darwin-x86-64/libtesseract.dylib) not found in resource path (/Users/lorenz/Desktop/sudoku_solver/target/classes:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/15.0.1/javafx-controls-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/15.0.1/javafx-controls-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/15.0.1/javafx-graphics-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/15.0.1/javafx-graphics-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/15.0.1/javafx-base-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/15.0.1/javafx-base-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/15.0.1/javafx-fxml-15.0.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/15.0.1/javafx-fxml-15.0.1-mac.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jna-5.11.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/tess4j-5.2.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/lept4j-1.16.1.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/fontbox-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/commons-io-2.11.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jbig2-imageio-3.0.4.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-tools-2.0.26.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/jboss-vfs-3.2.16.Final.jar:/Users/lorenz/Downloads/jar_files/pdfbox-debugger-2.0.26.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.extractFromResourcePath(Native.java:1145)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:275)
        ... 11 more
```

This is when I use version 5.2.1.

When I install version 4.2.1 i get another error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.TessBaseAPIDelete(net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITessAPI$TessBaseAPI)" because "this.api" is null
```

What is the problem with my installation?

Comment: See if [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21394537/ddg#30724844)

Comment: It seems unable to load SLF4J library. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421612/slf4j-failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder