# How do you install the x86_64 version of a brew package on a M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1, libsodium

I'm working on an **M1** processor and I'm running a setup script that needs access to the package libsodium which doesn't exist on my computer.

I run `brew install libsodium` which installs the package here **/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium** with all my other packages installed with brew

Re-running the setup script I get this error saying that it's looking for libsodium here **/usr/local/lib/sodium** which it can't find and that it found libsodium here **/opt/homebrew/lib/libsodium.dylib** but can't open it due to **an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')**

```
    LoadError: Could not open library 'sodium': dlopen(sodium, 0x0005): tried: 'sodium' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/sodium' (no such file), '/usr/lib/sodium' (no such file), '/Users/peter.walker/projects/chopin/sodium' (no such file).
Could not open library '/opt/homebrew/lib/libsodium.dylib': dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libsodium.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/libsodium.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium/1.0.18_1/lib/libsodium.23.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')).
```

How are you supposed to handle installing Intel only brew packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the command for installing x86_64 version of a brew package.

```
arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew install package
```

You might have to install brew for x86_64.

Comment: Is /usr/local/bin/brew in reference to where homebrew is installed?

Comment: Yes, it is. /usr/local/bin/ is the reference to x86_64 homebrew. And brew is the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle config set force_ruby_platform true`, `bundle install`, then `gem update --system` if you're getting this error message from trying to run a Rails app on M1.

The question I originally asked was unrelated to the issue I was having.