# How to inject property values into Spring Boot component

Tags: jdbc, spring-boot, configuration, spring-properties

In my Spring Boot Application, I implemented the following class with a method to call a stored procedure.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
public class FmTrfUtil {
    static int returnVal;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    static String url;

    public static int insertFmTrfs(List<String> trfs, String source) {
        System.out.println(url);
        EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RIStore_FM").createEntityManager();
        Session session = em.unwrap( Session.class );
        final String[] trfArray = trfs.toArray(new String[trfs.size()]);
        final String src = source;

        session.doWork( new Work(){
            public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                CallableStatement stmt = null;               
                OracleConnection oraCon = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
                Array array = oraCon.createARRAY("VARCHAR2_TAB_T", trfArray);
                stmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call FM_TRF_UTIL.process_fm_trf(?,?)}");
                stmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
                stmt.setArray(2, array);
                stmt.setString(3, src);
                stmt.execute();
                returnVal = stmt.getInt(1);
            }
        });
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Since calling stored procedure requires database connection, I need to load the these corresponding property values from application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xxx:389/risdev3, cn=OracleContext,dc=x,dc=net
spring.datasource.username=owner
spring.datasource.password=owner987
```

Based on the following articles about similar issue, [Spring boot - custom variables in Application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058814/spring-boot-custom-variables-in-application-properties) and [Using Spring-Boot configuration properties in your own classes](http://www.sothawo.com/2015/06/using-spring-boot-configuration-properties-in-your-own-classes/) and [Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties example](http://www.henryxi.com/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example), I added this annotation for my class `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")` (properties for db connection all have "spring" as prefix). However when I run it with a test class as follows, I got error "the application must supply JDBC connection" which means properties in application.properties are not picked up.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = RistoreWebApplication.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class FmTrfUtilTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<String> trfs = new ArrayList<String>();
        trfs.add("TRF000001");
        trfs.add("TRF000002");
        int ret = FmTrfUtil.insertFmTrfs(trfs, "SARC");
        assertTrue(ret > 0);
    }
}
```

In order for `@ConfigurationProperties` to work, I added maven dependency `spring-boot-configuration-processor` too. Why is it still not working? What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things wrong here:

- `@Value` does not work on static fields
- `@ConfigurationProperties` are used to bind fields from `application.properties` or `application.yml` to Java object. Look at any `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class from Spring Boot itself to easily understand how it should be used.
- you should not use your own `@ConfigurationProperties` with prefix `spring` since it's already used by Spring Boot itself
- `spring-boot-configuration-processor` is used only for nicer code completion in your IDE. You do not need this.

If you want to utilize Spring Boot configuration properties for database connection, instead of creating `EntityManager` like you do:

```
EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RIStore_FM").createEntityManager();
```

You should just inject it assuming you have Spring Data JPA Starter in your dependency list.

I see you use lots of `static` methods and fields. That's not going to work with Spring. Use dependency injection instead and autowire what you need.

Comment: How exactly should I inject em? I tried to inject `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "RIStore_FM")` `static EntityManager em;` just above the method, but got `Persistence annotations are not supported on static fields` error. If I take out the `static`, it will not compile saying em in the method must be declared static

Comment: Neither method nor field should be static. Look at Spring Data sample projects and reference. Using JPA with Spring is really simple if you do it Spring way.