# How to set build path configuration in spring boot webapp

Tags: spring, buildpath, application.properties

I am in new to spring boot. I have created a web app using spring boot. My application require some properties file to do the processing. In eclipse What I do i set the path on `Run configuration` like bellow.

[image: Bellow is the screen shot] 
  Now When I run the application I gets the require file on path and run smoothly.
Now I want to deploy the war file on some server. How do i provide this path to my application.

Bellow is the project structure of my project. and files are here
highlighted 
[image]

How do I set this file path using `application.properties` or any other way so that, I don't have to provide the path from run configuration, and the `.war` can be deploy on any server.

**Update 1** : This what I tried.
Created a `customStart.bat` 
content of the file is

```
set CATALINA_OPTS="-engine.home="/src/main/resources/" -Dlog4j.configuration=config/log4j.xml -Dlog4j.debug=true"
call startup.bat %CATALINA_OPTS%
```

But still that argument is not set. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As an option you can add your properties to %tomcat_home%\conf\catalina.properties

Just put them at the end of the file as follows:

log4j.configuration=config/log4j.xml
.....

Answer (score 0):

From spring boot official documentation (This is a highlight of the concept of creating custom spring boot variable) ***bellow*** you'll find a link to a Q/A that describes the solution.

> Spring Boot jars are shipped with meta-data files that provide details
>   of all supported configuration properties. The files are designed to
>   allow IDE developers to offer contextual help and “code completion” as
>   users are working with application.properties or application.yml
>   files.
>
> The majority of the meta-data file is generated automatically at
>   compile time by processing all items annotated with
>   @ConfigurationProperties. However, it is possible to write part of the
>   meta-data manually for corner cases or more advanced use cases.
>
> Configuration meta-data files are located inside jars under
>   META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json They use a simple JSON
>   format with items categorized under either “groups” or “properties”
>   and additional values hint categorized under "hints":

Here is an example of a meta data config file :

```
{"groups": [
    {
        "name": "server",
        "type": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties",
        "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties"
    },
    {
        "name": "spring.jpa.hibernate",
        "type": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate",
        "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties",
        "sourceMethod": "getHibernate()"
    }
    ...
],"properties": [
    {
        "name": "server.port",
        "type": "java.lang.Integer",
        "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties"
    },
    {
          "name": "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",
          "type": "java.lang.String",
          "description": "DDL mode. This is actually a shortcut for the \"hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto\" property.",
          "sourceType": "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate"
    }
    ...
],"hints": [
    {
        "name": "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",
        "values": [
            {
                "value": "none",
                "description": "Disable DDL handling."
            },
            {
                "value": "validate",
                "description": "Validate the schema, make no changes to the database."
            },
            {
                "value": "update",
                "description": "Update the schema if necessary."
            },
            {
                "value": "create",
                "description": "Create the schema and destroy previous data."
            },
            {
                "value": "create-drop",
                "description": "Create and then destroy the schema at the end of the session."
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

> Each “property” is a configuration item that the user specifies with a
>   given value. For example server.port and server.servlet-path might be
>   specified in application.properties as follows:
>
> server.port=9090 server.servlet-path=/home The “groups” are higher
>   level items that don’t themselves specify a value, but instead provide
>   a contextual grouping for properties. For example the server.port and
>   server.servlet-path properties are part of the server group.

**Notes:**

- **The groups** section *is note required*
- **“hints”** are additional information used to assist the user in configuring a given property. When configuring the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property, a tool can use it to offer some auto-completion help for the none, validate, update, create and create-drop values.

> You can easily generate your own configuration meta-data file from
>   items annotated with @ConfigurationProperties by using the
>   spring-boot-configuration-processor jar

---

You can check this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058814/spring-boot-custom-variables-in-application-properties)

** for more details check the spring boot apendix section **