# Spring Boot executable JAR: Write into application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, application.properties

I'm intending to write an executable JAR file (from command line) that will be run on scheduled base. After every run, some data needs to be stored in a file and evaluated in the next run (last run timestamp and some other values).

I was planing to store that values in application.properties since some other configuration data is already stored there.
But after doing some research I'm getting the impression that the purpose of application.properties is to provide configuration values in read-only fasion.

So is it possible to update the application.propoerties file during runtime by the executable itself or should I use another approach?

Comment: maybe take a look at this stackoverflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058814/spring-boot-custom-variables-in-application-properties