# How does Eclipse set Native.loadLibrary path?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, jar, java-8

I inherited a **working** large Java8 project that needs to be re-architected. It builds a jar, but also includes an example main (**not** included in the jar) and a deep tree of libs including some .dll files deep in the libs/ tree (dll's also **NOT** included in the jar).

At some point, the code in the jar calls Native.loadLibrary("fti2x.dll", fti2xWrapper.class, [Map< String, Integer>] options) on the simple file name "fti2x.dll" -- with no path components -- and the load succeeds. This .dll is only located deep in the libs/ directory on my computer. How did the jar, *running under eclipse*, figure out this was in /libs/client/usb/CommLib/amd64/fti2x.dll without specifying the path to it?

If I copy just the jar, the example main, and the libs/ directory to a new project, how do I configure it in Eclipse(Mars) to find the .dll for the Native.loadLibrary call? (Just simply doing so fails, so I am missing some config.)

How do I do execute the main.class outside of Eclipse and have it find the .dll?

Is there possibly some Java code I am missing that sets this path? If so, what do I look for?

Answer (score 0):

There is a system property that is used to specify the path that JNA uses to search for native libraries: `jna.library.path`.  Try printing out its value just after the library loads successfully in the old project to see if it is being set.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862391/how-to-pass-the-d-system-properties-while-testing-on-eclipse) explains how to set a system property in an Eclipse run configuration.  Outside of Eclipse, specify a value for it using the `-D` command-line switch to the JVM, e.g.

```
java -Djna.library.path=<some path> YourMainClass
```