# Giving three property file as input during maven build

Tags: java, maven

My code has three property file and I want to give input through maven. How to give input for three files in VM agrument.

[How to pass the -D System properties while testing on Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862391/how-to-pass-the-d-system-properties-while-testing-on-eclipse)​

I am following this link. But this link shows only for one property file. I want to give for three property file at once. Please suggest how to do it

Comment: You can add -Dlabel1="label_value1" -Dlabel2="label_value2".

Comment: The link you refer to, says to manually enter all properties as -Dkey=value in the panel.  Just do the same for all three property files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mentioned approach multiple times  like :

`-Dkey=value -Dkey2=value2 -Dkey3=value3`